# Autenticação no Facebook com Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sdk

Olá, estou com um probleminha ao estudar o Login do Facebook por JS.

Testando as permissões, fui no meu perfil do Facebook e retirei a permissão 'user_friends'. Ao entrar na página novamente, ele verifica se estou logado e verifica as permissões. Porém, ao redirecionar para dar novamente esta permissão, isto não aparece na janela de login, que fica branca e desaparece automaticamente.

Já tentei várias vezes e não consegui resolver. Podem me ajudar?

Link do arquivo: https://jsfiddle.net/ss9fqagr/

Comment: Poderia explicar um pouco melhor? Como assim "redirecionar para dar novamente esta permissão"? O que realmente quer fazer?

Comment: O código verifica se o usuário está conectado. Caso esteja, ele verifica se as permissões necessárias para o app estão concedidas pelo usuário. QUando qualquer uma delas está negada, ele redireciona para o login novamente, para que o usuário possa conceder esta permissão que falta. Entendeu? =)